# Download from browser when in amazon EC2 windows instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I am not able to download e.g. Google Chrome via Internet Explorer.

I also have a R-script that I'm able to run on my local PC, but not on my EC2 windows instance. The R-script logs in to Google Trends and pulls out search terms.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: If you are using `RStudio` then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16969504/1036500

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the issue. I think the issue has to to with some kind security setting on the EC2 windows instance.

Comment: Can you include the script you are trying to use?

Comment: It is no longer relevant for me. It was a scraping script.

Answer (score 2):

try to install chrome using power-shell. found working solution here.
https://superuser.com/a/1396175/904062

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell and hit this command

```
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object    System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```