# How do I do I write a script to export a data frame to my desktop from RStudio Server?

Tags: r, export, rscript, rstudio-server

I'm using RStudio Server version 0.99.903 and I want to create a script to export a data frame to my local machine running Windows 7. I can successfully export the data frame manually to the hard drive following the steps described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995963/3807006).

I have searched SO extensively. So far nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this would be very convenient.  I don't think rStudio server can do this (I can't find a way either).  It's relying on the browser to do the work of actually interacting with your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing since no access to Windows 7, based on [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091204091055AAZ01gw)

```
write_to_desktop <- function(df,fn="tmp.csv",...) {
   dskpath <- file.path("C:",Sys.getenv("USER"),"Desktop",fn)
   write.csv(df,file=dskpath,...)
}
```

You could modify this to try to guess the file name from the name of the data frame (`fn <- paste0(deparse(substitute(df)),".csv")`) or to write a `.rda` file (`save()`) or a `.rds` file (`saveRDS()`) ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very straightforward. However, I got an error when I ran the function:
`write_to_desktop (dfdata, "mydata.rda")`  

`Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :`   
   `cannot open the connection`

Comment: I should add when I check if mydata.rda exists and I know it exists the output is FALSE.    
`file.exists(file.path("C:", "Users", Sys.getenv("USER"),"Desktop","mydata.rda"))`   

`[1] FALSE`

Comment: how about `file.path(normalizePath("~/Desktop"),"mydata.rda")` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either and this may be due to the fact I'm using RStudio Server in the cloud i.e. within a browser (firefox 40.03). I may need to trigger a download event from the browser and that I don't know how to do it. Thanks again for your help.